# Prohibit site owner from deleting web part SP2010

Tags: web-part, permissions

Is there a way to stop site owners(Full Control-permission) from deleting a custom web part. I want to create a custom web part that can only be removed, closed or minimized by a specifically choosen user/group. Is that possible?
Im using SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, Site Owners (specifically anyone with Design or Full Control) can edit pages and change web parts. You would have to limit permissions for your users. The other alternative is to use a static Web part. This means adding the web part to a page but NOT in a web part zone. This will prevent users from removing the web part.